# Ionic3 background disappears when push a new page with Tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, tabs, ionic3

I try to push a new page with tabs in my app. However, I found when I click the button (add friends), the new page popup from right side and the background page suddenly disappears. when I click back button on the top left in new page(component). you will find that the background layer only shows white, and after the new page closing completely, the welcome page shows again.

example:

[image: example]

you can see my code below:

Here is the code if you need: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mfc3ga

> 1. open the link in Chrome
> 2. clicking "**open in new window**" on the top right of the page.
> 3. In new window, **open development tools**(Chrome) and switch to ***mobile model***(toggle device toolbar) and please refresh the browser.
> 4. clicking the "add friend button" on the top right.
> 5. you will see the background page(Welcome to Ionic) disappearing when the new page slides from right to left.
> 6. In addition, when you click back button on the top left in new page(component). you will find that the background layer only shows
>      white, and after the new page closing completely, the welcome page
>      shows again.

I have no idea what's wrong with my code.

Thanks Everyone

Comment: Hi Jake, please check the updated plunker and please describe more about what you were trying to achieve

Comment: Hello Suraj, my issue is that I have a new component, in this component, I have a tab inside this component. In the mobile model, when I push this new component using NavController, you will find the current page will disappear during the new component opening  and closing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**delete** `import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';` **to AboutPage**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
// import { AboutPage } from '../about/about'; DELETE THIS
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {
  tab1Root = HomePage;
  // tab2Root = AboutPage;
  tab3Root = ContactPage;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
}
```

in `app.module.ts`

remove: **AboutPage, ContactPage, HomePage,  TabsPage** on =>> **entryComponents**

```
 entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
  ],
```

and it works well ))

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I tried it, unfortunately, still have this issue.

Comment: look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-mfc3ga?file=pages%2Fabout%2Fabout.ts
 it works well

Comment: Yes, but you need to try it on mobile model in chrome. It works on web view but not on mobile view. Thanks

Comment: I check, unfortunately I still get this issue. sorry about that

Comment: He did not check on  stackblitz.com project